# Why does dismissViewControllerAnimated work in one case, but not in another?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am ***pushing*** content controllers onto the navigation controller.

I am **presenting** and **dismissing** the navigation controller.

I've tried 2 alternative ways to add a navigation button to a content controller to **dismiss the `UINavigationController`**, and both methods successfully call formDone, however, the first way results in a navigation controller that WONT be dismissed, even though `formDone` is called, while the second WILL dismiss the navigation controller as expected.  I can't even fathom what would cause such bizarre behavior.

Alternative 1:

```
contentController.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = 
    [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Back" 
                                     style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain 
                                     target:self 
                                     action:@selector(formDone)];
```

Alternative 2:

```
contentController.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = 
    [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemDone 
                                                   target:self 
                                                   action:@selector(formDone)];
```

Presenting code:

```
myNavigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] init];
[myNavigationController pushViewController:contentController animated:YES];
[myPresentingController presentViewController:myNavigationController animated:YES completion:^{}];
```

Dismissal Code:

```
-(void)formDone
    {
        [myPresentingController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{ }];
    }
```

Comment: it depends on how you made the view visible which you'd like to remove...? if you _pushed_ it into the nav-stack, you need to _pop_ it when you want to get rid of that; if you _presented_ it, you are able to _dismiss_ it.

Comment: In both cases I'm `presenting` it.  I'll update my code above

Comment: You're pushing... =>  `[myNavigationController pushViewController:contentController animated:YES];`

Comment: No, you're confused.  Im pushing the `CONTENT` controller.   What i'm talking about is dismissing the PRESENTED navigation controller, and clearly my code shows i am PRESENTING the navigation controller.

Comment: @LogicsaurusRex They should both work in the same way. Showing more of your code may help finding the issue. BTW, I don't know why you need a `myPresentingController`